# How to programmatically install "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607"

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 desktop machine and I want to install "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607".

I have managed to use PowerShell modules like https://www.petri.com/manage-windows-updates-with-powershell-module here to automate installation of the KBs.

The above mentioned module is also listed as KB3012973 but installing it via the below commands doesn't install it.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate

Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d -Confirm:$false

Get-WUInstall -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
```

It appears that this KB is in fact an ISO.
Can any one please help?

Comment: If you can't get it to work, [the Windows 10 ADK](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2015/08/11/download-windows-10-assessment-and-deployment-kit-adk/) provides tools for automating Windows installs/upgrades.  It's pretty complicated, mind you.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I couldn't get to automate it. Windows 10 ADK does seem complicated. Does C# allow us to do update Windows OS automatically?